# how to create a scatter plot for comparing 2 nested dictionaries with another nested dictionary with same keys

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matplotlib, nested

I have three nested dictionaries: data_geo1, data_geo2, data_ali, which all of them consist of two keys and one value. The goal is comparing the values with each other. The first key of dictionaries are the same but for the second one, the 30 of them shared with the first dictionary, and 20 of them shared with the second dictionary! Unfortunately, the orientation of the key is not in the same way to each other. The goal is creating a scatter plot with matplotlib and numpy array to compare the first and second dictionary with the data in data_ali. It's a bit complicated, and I don't know where to start!Here is what I have written for creating dictionaries:

```
import os
import numpy as np

path = "/home/ali/Desktop/data/"
root = "/home/ali/Desktop/SAMPLES/"



data_geo1={}
with open(path+"GSE98212_H_DE_genes_count.txt","rt") as fin: #data for sample 1-30
    h = fin.readline()
    sample1 = h.split()
    sample_names = [s.strip('"') for s in sample1[1:31]]
    for l in fin.readlines():
        l = l.strip().split()
        if l:
            gene= l[0].strip('"')
            data_geo1[gene] = {}
            for i, x in enumerate(l[1:31]):
                data_geo1[gene][sample_names[i]] = int(x)

#print(data_geo1)

data_geo2={}
with open (path+"GSE98212_L_DE_genes_count.txt","rt") as fin:
        h= fin.readline()
        sample2=h.split()
        sample_names=sample2[1:21]
        for l in fin.readlines():
            l = l.strip().split()
            if l:
                gene= l[0].strip()

            data_geo2[gene]={}
            for i,x in enumerate (l[1:21]):
                data_geo2[gene][sample_names[i]]= int(x)

#print(data_geo2)

data_ali={}

for sample_name in os.listdir(root):
    with open(os.path.join(root, sample_name, "counts.txt"), "r") as fin:
        for line in fin.readlines():
            gene, reads = line.split()
            reads = int(reads)
            if gene.startswith('ENSG'):
                data_ali.setdefault(gene, {})[sample_name] = reads

#print(data_ali)
```

the example of each dictionary structure:

data_geo1: {'ENSG00000110514': {'Sample_19-leish_023_v2': 709, 'Sample_4-leish_012_v3': 501, 'Sample_25-leish027_v2': 690, 'Sample_6-leish_015_v3': 463, 'Sample_23-leish026_v2': 707, 'Sample_20-leish_023_v3': 619, 'Sample_18-leish_022_v3': 678, 'Sample_10-leish_017_v3': 477, 'Sample_13-leish_019_v2': 460, 'Sample_1-Leish_011_v2': 574, 'Sample_11-leish_018_v2': 566, 'Sample_3-leish_012_v2': 632, 'Sample_2-leish_011_v3': 388, 'Sample_29-leish032_v2': 661, 'Sample_8-leish_016_v3': 372, 'Sample_28-leish028_v3': 533, 'Sample_27-leish028_v2': 582, 'Sample_26-leish027_v3': 624, 'Sample_12-leish_018_v3': 653, 'Sample_5-leish_015_v2': 421, 'Sample_16-leish_021_v3': 376, 'Sample_21-leish_024_v2': 668, 'Sample_9-leish_017_v2': 583, 'Sample_24-leish026_v3': 590, 'Sample_22-leish_024_v3': 537, 'Sample_14-leish_019_v3': 438, 'Sample_30-leish032_v3': 494, 'Sample_7-leish_016_v2': 518, 'Sample_15-leish_021_v2': 834, 'Sample_17-leish_022_v2': 742}

data_geo2:{'ENSG00000110514': {'Sample_19': 518, 'Sample_10': 468, 'Sample_20': 517, 'Sample_9': 431, 'Sample_8': 522, 'Sample_7': 437, 'Sample_6': 491, 'Sample_5': 461, 'Sample_4': 442, 'Sample_3': 667, 'Sample_2': 438, 'Sample_1': 378, 'Sample_14': 345, 'Sample_13': 424, 'Sample_18': 570, 'Sample_15': 492, 'Sample_16': 486, 'Sample_12': 401, 'Sample_17': 489, 'Sample_11': 464}

data_ali: 'ENSG00000110514': {'Sample_19-leish_023_v2': 710, 'Sample_16-leish_021_v3': 380, 'Sample_20': 517, 'Sample_24-leish026_v3': 593, 'Sample_6-leish_015_v3': 468, 'Sample_12-leish_018_v3': 661, 'Sample_22-leish_024_v3': 539, 'Sample_23-leish026_v2': 710, 'Sample_25-leish027_v2': 689, 'Sample_18-leish_022_v3': 681, 'Sample_14': 346, 'Sample_2-leish_011_v3': 394, 'Sample_13-leish_019_v2': 464, 'Sample_1-Leish_011_v2': 574, 'Sample_11-leish_018_v2': 571, 'Sample_20-leish_023_v3': 625, 'Sample_3-leish_012_v2': 637, 'Sample_10-leish_017_v3': 479, 'Sample_7': 436, 'Sample_29-leish032_v2': 659, 'Sample_8-leish_016_v3': 375, 'Sample_6': 492, 'Sample_7-leish_016_v2': 517, 'Sample_9': 432, 'Sample_8': 521, 'Sample_27-leish028_v2': 584, 'Sample_26-leish027_v3': 629, 'Sample_5': 460, 'Sample_4': 441, 'Sample_3': 668, 'Sample_19': 516, 'Sample_1': 378, 'Sample_2': 437, 'Sample_9-leish_017_v2': 582, 'Sample_5-leish_015_v2': 421, 'Sample_4-leish_012_v3': 502, 'Sample_21-leish_024_v2': 670, 'Sample_18': 573, 'Sample_13': 426, 'Sample_12': 403, 'Sample_11': 463, 'Sample_10': 466, 'Sample_17': 488, 'Sample_16': 487, 'Sample_15': 490, 'Sample_14-leish_019_v3': 441, 'Sample_30-leish032_v3': 497, 'Sample_28-leish028_v3': 542, 'Sample_15-leish_021_v2': 837, 'Sample_17-leish_022_v2': 747}

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to "unwrap" the dictionaries like this:

```py
main_key=u'ENSG00000110514'

geo1_labels = data_geo1[main_key].keys() 
geo1_ys = [data_geo1[main_key][x] for x in geo1_labels]
ali_geo1_ys = [data_ali[main_key][x] for x in geo1_labels]

geo2_labels = data_geo2[main_key].keys() 
geo2_ys = [data_geo2[main_key][x] for x in geo2_labels]
ali_geo2_ys = [data_ali[main_key][x] for x in geo2_labels]
```

and then you can e.g. scatter plot the values for comparison like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax=plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(range(len(geo1_labels)),geo1_ys,facecolors="None",edgecolors="b",marker="o")
ax.scatter(range(len(geo1_labels)),ali_geo1_ys,facecolors="None",edgecolors="r",marker="s")

ax.set_xticks(range(len(geo1_labels)) )
ax.set_xticklabels(geo1_labels,rotation=90)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

---

**Update:**
There are several ways to get to the plots you described, one approach would use the module `pandas`; in this specific case, this may seem to require more effort at first, but it is quite popular:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

main_key=u'ENSG00000110514'

compare1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'data_geo2':data_geo1[main_key],
    'data_ali':{k:data_ali[main_key][k] for k in data_geo1[main_key].keys()}
},orient='index')

compare2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'data_geo2':data_geo2[main_key],
    'data_ali':{k:data_ali[main_key][k] for k in data_geo2[main_key].keys()}
},orient='index')

compare1['Sample_19-leish_023_v2'].plot.bar()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

and another option would just straight use the above dicts for plotting:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

main_key=u'ENSG00000110514'
sample_key=u'Sample_19-leish_023_v2'

fig,ax=plt.subplots()

xs=[0,1]
ys=[ data_geo1[main_key][sample_key], data_ali[main_key][sample_key] ]

ax.bar(xs,ys)
ax.set_xticks(xs)
ax.set_xticklabels(['data_geo1','data_ali'])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for your advice but the main key as you writes just for one key but my keys are variable and like this: 'ENSG00000268358' , 'ENSG00000254148', 'ENSG00000254148', 'ENSG00000254148' and etc. how can i solve this to go through each of these keys ? these keys are all mutual among 3  dictionaries! they are gene 1 and gene 2 and gene in 3 dictionaries that i have created above !

Comment: Ah, this wasn't clear from your original question. Do these other dicts still contain ”unified" keys on the second level, i.e. will you have keys like `Sample_19` or `Sample_19-leish_023_v2` in them? Do you, in the end, want to join all of one type (e.g. with "*leish*" in the key)  in one large plot? Also, do you need to keep track of the main keys in some way, or could they be dropped?

Comment: I am sorry that I couldn't precisely clarify myself. I write above my code of how dictionaries constructed, and you can notice for each dictionary that I have 'gene' key common with others. I want to compare  "data_geo1" and "data_geo2" values with "data_ali" values. for the second level key "data_geo1" has 30 keys and "data_geo2" 20 keys and data_ali has 50 keys that mean all the keys that existed in "data_geo1" and "data_geo2" we have them in "data_ali"! so it's better to compare them with the first level key.

Comment: i just need to compare the values but the exact one with another! e.g compare data_geo1 'ENSG00000110514' 'Sample_19-leish_023_v2 with data_ali 'ENSG00000110514' 'Sample_19-leish_023_v2' . was it clear? the purpose is to compare data_geo1 and data_geo2 with data_ali

Comment: Just to be clear: you have a list of dictionaries with main keys like `'ENSG00000110514'`, and want to be able to plot the values of a specific sample e.g.`Sample_19-leish_023_v2` [perhaps as a `.bar()` plot in matplotlib?] from the two dictionaries `data_geo1` and `data_ali` for the same main key? In the example above, you would then only want to plot y-values: [709,710] and x-values["data_geo1","data_ali"] in one figure?

Comment: yes exactly for the first part of your question! i want to to plot all the values for a main key that belongs to a specific sample! and yes exactly i want to do plot y-values and x-values as you mentioned! thank for your patient and help!

Comment: @ALIHAKIMZADEH : I've updated my answer (see above)

Comment: thanks for your help i try to do it as a cycle to go through all my main keys